# Castle Windsor Activation Error IController, key "home"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor

I am getting the following error:

> Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException was unhandled
>   by user code   Message=Activation error occured while trying to get
>   instance of type IController, key "home"
>   Source=Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type
>   serviceType, String key) in
>   c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line
>   57
>          at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance[TService](String
>   key) in
>   c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line
>   103
>          at AN.Core.Windsor.Web.WindsorControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName)   InnerException:
>   System.MissingMethodException
>          Message=Method not found: 'Castle.Core.Internal.GraphNode[] Castle.Core.Internal.GraphNode.get_Dependers()'.
>          Source=AN.Core.Windsor.Web
>          StackTrace:
>               at AN.Core.Windsor.Web.WindsorServiceLocator.DoGetInstance(Type
>   serviceType, String key)
>               at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type
>   serviceType, String key) in
>   c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line
>   49
>          InnerException:

I do have a HomeController:

```
public interface IHomeController
{
    ActionResult Index();
}

public class HomeController : Controller, IHomeController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        RegistrationModel model = new RegistrationModel();
        model.FillTestData();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Here is my initialization code in my global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    BootstrapWindsorContainer();
}

private static void BootstrapWindsorContainer()
{
    _container = new WindsorContainer()
        .Install(FromAssembly.InThisApplication());             

    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new WindsorServiceLocator(_container));

    var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory();
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
}
```

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 1):

I carried out these steps to get it working in a test project:

```
Install-Package Castle.Windsor.Web.Mvc
```

Made a slight change to the `WindsorControllerFactory` constructor to pass in the `_container` as below:

```
    private static void BootstrapWindsorContainer()
    {
        _container = new WindsorContainer()
            .Install(FromAssembly.InThisApplication());

        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new WindsorServiceLocator(_container));

        var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(_container);
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
    }
```

The parameterless constructor below:

```
 var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory();
```

Results in this error:

```
Plumbing.WindsorControllerFactory' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
```